# JetBrains IDE - how to remove selection after "Alt+Shift+Enter"

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I pressed <kbd>Alt + Shift + Enter</kbd> and in result selected code area was colored to the lavender blue (#CCCCFF), as in the picture below. I want to remove this selection. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: What keymap do you use? `Alt+Shift+Enter` shortcut does not do anything like that here on my Windows. You can go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and use "Find Actions by Shortcut" button there (next to the local search field) -- it will show what actions may have such shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK -- I think I know what you mean now: looks like it's a duplicate code fragment and you have used `Show all duplicates like this` action when popup with the message was shown, e.g.

[image]
*Such shortcut seems to be hardcoded and cannot be modified (hence no matches on the Keymap settings screen)*

The result (editor):

[image]

#### Solution:

To get rid of the "selection" just hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.